# firebase ionic3 retrive specific data without node key

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

```
getFeedsByTheme(theme:any):Promise<any> {
    console.log("theme",theme);
    const ref = 
firebase.database().ref('dailyfeeds').orderByChild('theme').equalTo(theme);
```

I want to retrieve data from a firebase database. Below is my structure of the database, in that I want to retrieve data which matches the particular given theme. How could I achieve that?

[image: Database structure]

Right now I'm doing something like this:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('dailyfeeds').orderByChild('theme').equalTo(theme);
```

Comment: Please post some code on what you've tried so far.

Comment: i have tried 
getFeedsByTheme(theme:any):Promise<any> {
    console.log("theme",theme);
    const ref = firebase.database().ref('dailyfeeds').orderByChild('theme').equalTo(theme);

but im getting null

Comment: What is theme here? `equalTo(theme)`?

Comment: mind or health which is selected by user

Comment: yes but theme is a key and it's not equal to mind or health, it has children that have the values mind or health. That's why you get null

Comment: ohk got it so how can i achieve that can you help me

Comment: is there anything i can do to retrive the same